# How to use JavaFX in Main

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I am completly lost atm. I have been working with scenebuilder and javaFX in the past but I am stuck like 5 hours now and I didnt get a step further. Let me explain:

- I have a working java Eclipse Project, using maven dependencies
- The Main is where I want to use JavaFX or load a fxml into
- The programm takes many many VCC Files and extracts the data to put it all together in an excel
- The programm works but I cant load a FXML file into the main or even show a pane in there

---

Now does my Java Main class has to extend Application? I tried both ways - doenst work.

Some example code:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        bpmain = new BorderPane(FXMLLoader.load(new File("src\\fxml\\UserInterface.fxml").toURI().toURL()));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(bpmain));
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

or this (from original Docs)

```
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Circle circ = new Circle(40, 40, 30);
    Group root = new Group(circ);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);

    stage.setTitle("My JavaFX Application");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

but this start method is just not getting called... where do I put that?

---

What my Programm should look like is pretty simple actually. I want a small UI Windows that lets you pick a Folder where the VCC data lives in and a OK Button that basically should run the Main method.

So a TextField that when its picked a Path in the Main gets replaced (filepath) and just a simple OK Button that says: yeah run the main - because the main works perfectly it is just that I cant show that ui and I dont know how to really connect it to the Main.java

Any help is appreciated - Ty

Comment: Did you call `javafx.application.launch()` in `main`? That bootstraps the fx application. Then your app must extend `Application` and override the `start()` method, not just re-declare it.

Comment: Yeah I dont really get that. Can I make a MainFX that extends application with the start method and then in my normal java main where would I call it ?

Comment: Your app extends `Application`. It has a `main` method that calls `launch()`. It overrides `start()`. There's not supposed to be any other main method than the one mentioned. All the rest should be triggered by the app, either by user interface interaction, in the start method or in some startup events that might be there.

Comment: Okay I actually got something shown (the UI from docs) - thanks for now I will come back if I have more questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

```
public class Launch extends Application {

    public static Stage stage = null;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        this.stage = stage;
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**Option 2:**

```
   public class SidebarController implements Initializable {
    
        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    
        }    
        
        @FXML
        void btnHome_OnMouseClicked(MouseEvent event) throws IOException {
      BorderPane borderPane = (BorderPane) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getRoot();
            Parent sidebar = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/ContentArea.fxml"));
            borderPane.setCenter(sidebar);
    
        }
}
```